# QGIS save layer as converts Layer Field Data Type

Tags: qgis

In QGIS I open a geodatabase and save one layer to a SHP file to work on.  I use the "Save Layer As" option with the default settings.  However I discovered that the SHP Field data type changes, in particular a "Date" type is saved to a "Text" type. I only discovered the issue when I was trying to use the field calculator and there were issues when using text in calculations.

Is there a setting I am missing that maintains the original data types.

Original Data Type from ArcCatalogue
[image]

QGIS data type
[image]

Comment: Before opening QGIS, you could have check what ArcCatalog tells you when you open your SHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shapefiles can store dates only in the format YYYY-MM-DD (shapefile is a very old dBase format storing dates with four bytes). A geodatabase format from ArcMap/ArcCatalog has the format 2019-01-15T07:33:12.000 which stores also the time. Exporting to shapefile stores your geodatabase date to a string, then you don't loose information. You can use **geopackage** instead, which will convert the geodatabase date into a QDateTime format which is the same like in ArcCatalog.